Complex model relation in SwiftData
I'm having trouble solving the following problem. I want to create a workout app where the user can see their workout history and exercise progress. To achieve this, I'm using SwiftData to model the relationship between workouts and exercises in such a way that:

Exercises are not dependent on workouts.
Workouts are not dependent on exercises.

Here's what I have in mind:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Workout: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var id: UUID
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var relations: [WorkoutExericise]?
    
    init(name: String = "", id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

@Model
class WorkoutExericise: Identifiable {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Workout.relations) var workout: Workout
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Exercise.relations) var exercise: Exercise
    var sets: [ExerciseSet]
    var id: UUID
    
    init(workout: Workout, exercise: Exercise, sets: [ExerciseSet] = [], id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.workout = workout
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.sets = sets
        self.id = id
    }
}

@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var id: UUID
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var relations: [WorkoutExericise]?
    
    init(name: String = "", id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

struct ExerciseSet: Codable {
    var reps: Int
    var weight: Float
}

The problem is that this example doesn't work when deleting a Workout or Exercise that has a relation. Am I overcomplicating things? Or am I just making a mistake? This is my first project with SwiftData.

doesn't work, this isn’t very helpful. Please add some more context

"doesn't work when deleting a Workout or Exercise". I don't know the problem cause, but must be related to the fact that when you delete a Workout, causing the WorkoutExercise related to be deleted, somehow the Exercise associate keep the information of the WorkoutExercise, which keeps the information of the Workout.

Ok so you have problems with the delete rules it seems. They are unfortunately not working properly so you need to manually delete any relevant objects

You typically don't want a cascade delete rule on both sides of a relationship. Deleting a Workout would delete all its WorkoutExercises, and deleting each of them will delete their Exercise. You could replace the relationships defined in WorkoutExercise with .nullify, or omit the delete rule together. In fact, you probably don't need the @Relationship macro in there at all – SwiftData should be able to infer the relationship without it.
